# Go GORM and interfaces

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a lot of different tables (60) with different structures. I don't want write create() / read() methods for all. The best solution for me is using interface. But GORM dont want to work correct with interface

```
var b = model.SomeTable{}
// var b = model.factory(some_name)

func(in interface{}) {
    err = postgres.DB.First(&in).Error
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}(b)
```

> (unsupported destination, should be slice or struct)

Comment: change to `...First(in).Er..` and `..}(&b)..`

Comment: it will be work. But I have the `func factory(string) interface{}` I have to work with it

Comment: Then just have the factory return a pointer and you won't have to get the address of `in` or `b` after that. [Here's an example](https://play.golang.org/p/Q91aMUGlgK)